# Concatenate to a list of string another string

Tags: string, list, haskell, concatenation

The below code gives back a list of String but I want it work on multiple cases. The problem is that I can't create the same exact result with recursion.
The program gives back the following result:

```
replaceTabs 6 ["\thello world"]

=> ["      hello world"]
```

Now this should work with a longer list like:

```
replaceTabs 6 ["asd dsa","\thello world"]

    => ["asd dsa","      hello world"]
```

Simple concat doesn't work, because it will give back undefined pattern.

```
replaceTab' :: Int -> [[Char]] -> [Char]
replaceTab' n [[x]] =
 if x == '\t' then replicate n ' '
 else [x]

replaceTabs :: Int -> [String]-> [String]
replaceTabs n [""] = [""]
replaceTabs n (x:xs) = (return . concat $ [replaceTab' n [a] | a <- (map (:[]) (x))])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
replaceTab' :: Int -> [[Char]] -> [Char]
```

is the same as,

```
replaceTab' :: Int -> [String] -> String
```

What you should focus on is implementing a function,

```
replaceTab :: Int -> String -> String
```

which "fixes" a single `String`. Then `replaceTabs` is simply,

```
replaceTabs :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
replaceTabs n = map (replaceTab n)
```